# Can't get child class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get value of an input(class = get_user_option) in a label. My codes from html are : It's a multiple choice question format. When user picking a specific option, it should get that specific option. But I am getting the last clicked option for all questions. I mean all question getting the same option although they are different

```
 <form action="{{url('user-test-submition')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
 <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body text-center" style="background: 
      black;color:white">
      <p><i class="fas fa-clock mr-4"></i><b>Remaining Time : <span 
      id="time">{{$test_info->duration}}</span> minutes!</b></p>
     </div>
    <input type="text" value="{{$test_info->test_name}}" 
    name="test_name">
    <input type="text" value="{{$test_info->id}}" name="test_id">
    <input type="text" value="4" name="user_id">
                        
                        
        @foreach($test_questions as $test_question)
        <div class="card-body test-question" data-id=" 
        {{$test_question->id}}">
        <p><b>{{$test_question->question_number}} ) {{$test_question- 
        >question}}</b></p>
        <input type="text" class="correct_answer" value=" 
        {{$test_question->correct_option_name}}" 
        name="correct_answer[]">
        <input type="text" value="{{$test_question->id}}" 
        name="test_question_id[]">
        <input type="text" class="user_answer" value="" 
        name="user_answer[]">
        <input type="text" class="answer_status" value="" 
        name="answer_status[]">
            @foreach($test_question->questions as $question_option)
                          
            <label data-id="{{$question_option->id}}" 
            class="get_user_option">
                            
            <input type="radio" class="answer_option" value=" 
            {{$question_option->correct_option_name}}" name=" 
            {{$question_option->question_id}}" /><span 
            class="option_content">{{$question_option->option_name}} 
            </span> {{$question_option->option_content}}</label>
            @endforeach
                           
        </div>
        @endforeach
                     
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="">
       <!-- <a href="{{url('test/result')}}" class="btn btn- 
       danger">Submit</a> -->
    </div>
 </form>
```

Codes from Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.answer_option').on('change',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var ele = $(this);

   var option = $(this).parents("label").find(".option_content").html();
   var notOp = ele.parent(".test-question").find(".user_answer").val();
   var correct_answer = ele.parent(".get_user_option").children(".answer_option").val();
   console.log(correct_answer);
   ele.parents("div").find(".user_answer").val(option);
   ele.parents("div").find(".answer_status").val(1);
 })
 });
```

The output in console :

[image]

Jquery Rendered HTML is here :

```
 <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-test-submition" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" 
    value="Tyag9602FC3zkLuKVCINKSGEDyjfZOE0sjCOEMoP">                       
   <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body text-center" style="background: 
   black;color:white">
   <p><i class="fas fa-clock mr-4" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>Remaining 
   Time : <span id="time">04:35</span> minutes!</b></p>
   </div>
   <input type="text" value="BCS math" name="test_name">
   <input type="text" value="12" name="test_id">
   <input type="text" value="4" name="user_id">
                        
                        
   <div class="card-body test-question" data-id="36">
   <p><b>1 ) 1+5=?</b></p>
   <input type="text" class="correct_answer" value="b" 
   name="correct_answer[]">
   <input type="text" value="36" name="test_question_id[]">
   <input type="text" class="user_answer" value="" name="user_answer[]">
   <input type="text" class="answer_status" value="" 
   name="answer_status[]">
                                                                   
   <label data-id="34" class="get_user_option">
   <!-- <label class="hi"></label> -->
   <input type="radio" class="answer_option" value="" name="36"><span 
   class="option_content">a</span> 3</label>
                                                      
   <label data-id="35" class="get_user_option">
   <!-- <label class="hi"></label> -->
   <input type="radio" class="answer_option" value="" name="36"><span 
   class="option_content">b</span> 1</label>
                                                       
  </div>                 
                                                 
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="">
  <!-- <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/result" class="btn btn- 
  danger">Submit</a> -->
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The code sample you've shown appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cjw9m5dy/. However I can see it references HTML elements which you've not included in the question. Please provide a clear problem statement.

Comment: I can't tell which line can't find what you are looking for. To debug this, instead of chaining thing like `$(this).parents("label").find(".option_content")`, assign each to a variable to see which is null.

Comment: Also, please tag your questions appropriately. PHP and Laravel are not relevant to this issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The issue is, since it's a loop, radio inputs(multiple) are loaded according to the numbers assigned in table. Now, when I am clicking a radio option, It returns undefined value in console

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have checked, .option_content returns null/undefined

Comment: @Tamanna The numbers aren't relevant though, as you're using DOM traversal. The example in the jsFiddle works absolutely fine. The issue may be clearer if you could post the actual HTML output, showing the values coming from the server side code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question with screenshot, please watch that

Comment: The screenshot is not helpful. As Rory said, please post the _relevant_ HTML that your PHP application actually renders.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have updated the html, Please watch . thanks

Comment: @Tamanna, that is still PHP/blade, we are asking for you to post the relevant rendered HTML since that is what jQuery is interpreting. See Rory's first fiddle for an example.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have added the rendered html, is that what you were asking ? sorry for not getting it early

Comment: I _think_ `ele.parent(".test-question")` should be `ele.parents(".test-question")` because you need to walk higher in the DOM than just a single parent. After that, I'm not really clear on your logic. This would probably be a good place for some code comments and obviously-named variables.

Comment: Honestly, I don't use jQuery, modern JS can be very expressive on its own. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/nm7suokd/) a version in pure JS with only two changes where I added two attributes to your radio, because parsing HTML is asking for problems, which should be 100% doable in your blade code. This code is more verbose, but I think it reads really clearly and obviously, and there isn't a whole lot of magic, or if there is, it is contained to a context.

Comment: As no-one else has posted it yet, please see [mcve]. There's a lot of code there that can't all be *relevant*.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for all your suggestions, I have fixed it by changing parents('div') to parents('.test-question')

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion @freedomn-m